# Issue with writing to a text file

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a program where I want to be able to add a `Surfer` (a class that requires four strings, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Dob`, `Country`). (I did not use `DateTime` as it wasn't a necessity for this project although it is probably better practice to use it.) I then wanted to write the class I just created to a text file, and I have a formatted string for this. I have two issues.

1. It is not writing the `Dob` or the `Country` to the text file.
2. I am not sure how to put each entry on a new line. (i have tried \n
   at the end of my FileFormat string and seperately at the end of my
   string `toFile`.

The code I have for attempting to do this is

```
public class Surfer
{
    protected string SurferFirstName { get; set; }
    protected string SurferLastName { get; set; }
    protected string SurferDob { get; set; }
    protected string SurferCountry { get; set; }
    public Surfer() { }

    public Surfer(string surferFirstName, string surferLastName, string surferDob, string surferCountry)
    {
        SurferFirstName = surferFirstName;
        SurferLastName = surferLastName;
        surferDob = SurferDob;
        surferCountry = SurferCountry;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Surfer name:  {0} {1}   Surferdob:  {2} \n Country:  {3}", SurferFirstName, SurferLastName, SurferDob, SurferCountry);
    }
    //for display in the textblock, virtual for inheritance
   /* public virtual string vehicleDetails()
    {
        return string.Format("Make:{0,40} \nModel:{1,40} \nPrice:{2,40} \nYear: {3,40} \nColour: {4,40}, \nMileage: {5,40} \nDescription: {6,40} \nEngine: {7,40}", Make, Model, Price, Year, Colour, Mileage, Description, Engine);
    }*/
    //for formatting to a text file
    public string FileFormat()
    {
        return string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3} \n", SurferFirstName, SurferLastName, SurferDob, SurferCountry);

    }
}
```

My code is the WindowAdd.cs

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //reading in from text boxes
    string fName = txtbxFirstName.Text;
    string lName = txtbxLastName.Text;
    string dob = txtbxDob.Text;
    string country = txtbxCountry.Text;
    //basic validation
    if (fName.Length <2 || lName.Length <2 )
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("first and last name must be entered");
    }
    else if(dob.Length <10 || dob.Length>10)
        MessageBox.Show("Enter dob in the correct format (dd/mm/yyyy)");
    else if(country.Length <3)
        MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid country");
    else
    {
        try
        {
            //sets mainWindow
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            //creates new surfer class
            Surfer newSurfer = new Surfer(fName, lName, dob, country);
            //adds to observable collection
            mainWindow.surfers.Add(newSurfer);
            //uses FileFormat from the Surfer Class to format in order to add to text file
            string toFile = newSurfer.FileFormat();
            //append to Surfers.Text
            File.AppendAllText("Surfers.Text", toFile);

            //closes window
            this.Close();
        }
```

The result I am getting in the text file is like this

> John,Barry,,  Happy,Gilmore,,

this is for two attempted entries

The basic validation is working so it is reading in from the xaml okay. I know I could use `File.WriteAllLines` and write code to send every element in my observable collection to the text file through a save button, but if possible I would rather do it in a manner similar to the method I am trying, where I save one entry to the textfile at a time without deleting existing elements.

Comment: On windows you want to use `\r\n` for newline, or just use `Environment.NewLine`. On my system regular Notepad will not display `\n` as a new line (other editors will, though).

Comment: That solved the new line issue Cheers!

Comment: You have your variables backwards in the `Surfer` constructor, `surferDob = SurferDob` should be `SurferDob = surferDob`, likewise with `SurferCountry`

Comment: Thank you for that, I thought I must have done something stupid but I could not see where I went wrong despite ages looking

Comment: I had used `\r\n` initially and although it appeared to write to the txt file in the right manner it caused an error when reading in from a text file. so i used your second suggestion`Environment.NewLine` instead which worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You constructor is assigning variables the wrong direction for Dob and  Country. You're assigning the property into the parameter, instead of parameter into the property.

```
public Surfer(string surferFirstName, string surferLastName, string surferDob, string surferCountry)
        {
            SurferFirstName = surferFirstName;
            SurferLastName = surferLastName;
            surferDob = SurferDob;
            surferCountry = SurferCountry;
        }
```

For new lines, use `Environment.NewLine` as suggested above by Quantic.

Comment: This is why I'm a big proponent of the 'this' keyword for member fields and properties.  It avoids stuff like this.